# Search URL on the new LinkedIn UI

Tags: url, search, linkedin-api

Looks like LinkedIn has a new UI and seems to be slowly rolling out to everyone. We have a LinkedIn button on our site that looks up a prospect by their name and company and searches LI. Currently, this works for the "oldLinkedIn" but for me, I'm somehow on the "nuLinkedIn" and this search URL doesn't render properly. Our current search URL for oldLinkedIn will populate this: http://www.linkedin.com/search/fpsearch?company=salesforce&fname=carden&lname=wyckoff&currentCompany=C For me, this loads a blank page with just the LinkedIn logo, but for another employee still on the oldLinkedin it renders properly and can see the client. When I do a manual search for this person in nuLinkedIn, this is the URL https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/index/?keywords=carden%20wyckoff%20salesforce&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER we are  trying to figure out what the new URL search query is so we can update our search button for linkedin. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you change your populated URL to:

[https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/index/?keywords=firstname%3A"carden"%20AND%20lastname%3A"wyckoff"%20AND%20company%3A"salesforce"&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER](https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/index/?keywords=firstname%3A%22carden%22%20AND%20lastname%3A%22wyckoff%22%20AND%20company%3A%22salesforce%22&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER)

it should work.
Obviously you can use OR instead of AND in there for more results.

Fields you can search are:

- firstname: Finds members based on first name
- lastname: Finds members based on last name
- title: Finds members based on their current title
- company: Finds members based on their current company (keyword search)
- school: Finds members based on schools attended (keyword search)

Comment: Note: These changes will not work on the old version of linkedIn ... so you'll need some what to distinguish between users on the old and users on the new.

Comment: can it be made dynamic? I mean to say that linkedin keeps on changing the search URL, is there any way by which it could be done?

Comment: This is not working anymore on our production environment, Any help would be appriciated